# Is the phrase 'get me started' in the idiom "don't get me started" an example of causative?

Tags: idioms, causative-verbs

To me, the boldfaced part of '*don't **get me started***' looks like a causative because of the form:

*get + object + past participle*

and the meaning:

> *More often, the intent is negative and the expression is used to express exasperation or strong dislike, etc.* *There may [be] an element of warning in it: If I start talking about this, I’ll never stop!*"- *Idioms Online*

I'd say that, in a way, the idiom implies that the subject of this imperative sentence may cause the speaker to start endlessly talking about something in an extremely emotional way just by mentioning the topic.

At the same time, this meaning is closer to causative 'make', which uses a different grammar pattern (make +object + infinitive).

So, I'm in doubt about grammatical category of "get me started" in the mentioned idiom.

Please advise whether my reasoning appropriately places it in the causative category, or is it some different piece of grammar?

P.S. I've looked through the forum, Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage*, consulted some other resources, and, naturally, Googled it, but none of that has brought much clarity, hence, posting the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Don't get me started* is a fixed phrase with a specific meaning. The *don't* is required; the whole thing is short for *Don't let me start to talk about X*.

The phrase *get X started* (where X is something startable, like a job or a motor or a list of complaints) means to cause X to be in a "started" condition, which may mean a lot of things, but in this idiom refers only to the speaker's potential complaints having a beginning but not an end.

The fact that *cause* is part of the meaning of the idiom makes it a causative construction. There is no formula for causatives in English grammar, so "causative" is not a grammatical term in English, but descriptive, like saying *to smoke* in *He stopped to smoke* is a "purpose infinitive". There's nothing marked as "purpose", but that's what it means; and there's nothing marked as "causative", either.

Other ways to indicate causation abound

- *I got him to mow the lawn*.
- *I had him mow the lawn.*
- *I told/ordered/forced/hired him to mow the lawn.*

These are all causatives, too, but not because of their grammar.

Comment: The phrase "to get someone going" [can have a similar meaning,](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+him+going) but it doesn't require the "don't."

Comment: Yes, that's a general construction - get X V-ing - _We got them singing finally, He got the door off/open/closed/closing properly_

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you so much, Professor Lawler! Your detailed answer is of so much help, as well as the main principle of defining the causative in various constructions. I'm thrilled to read your articles and other numerous contributions to this website.

Comment: Well ‘got him to mow’ and ‘had him mow’ are causatives in a completely different way from “told/ordered/hired’. The first are only true if the mowing took place and was caused by the subject. Neither of those requirements is necessary for the truth of the latter group of sentences.

Comment: That's why "causative" isn't a technical term in English syntax. Like "future" or "mood", they're evocative instead of definitive.

Comment: I agree with your analysis that _started_ is an adjective in the construction. But none of the examples you've provided includes an adjective after the object of 'the causative verb'. Do you also consider _make_ a causative verb in _Don't make me angry_?

Comment: @JohnLawler If you don't consider the _make_ a causative verb, why would you consider OP's _get_ one?